# PhpStorm - where are the FTP error logs located?

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

I've got some weird and intermittent FTP issue with PhpStorm, where when transferring files the latter gets FTP error 3/5 times, while other FTP clients are fine. Unfortunately PhpStorm doesn't give meaningful errors, it just says:

```
Failed to collect files: Could not connect to FTP server on "----.com".
```

I'd like to know exactly what the FTP said, the error flags, number, etc. I can't seem to find these info on PhpStorm.

Other infos:

1. Using latest PHP version as of date.
2. Compared with FileZilla, using same settings, including auth, transfer mode, etc. Identical!
3. Everything worked fine in PhpStorm until 3 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

There are no separate FTP logs of any kind (not collected by default).

If you need to see such detailed FTP logs:

1. Enable such extra logging first: `#com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment`

   - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-deployment.html#31fe36c1
   - or https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs
2. Do your FTP activities
3. Check `idea.log` for details (this file contains all the logs from all subsystems).

   To access it use `Help | Show Log in XXX` (where XXX will be default File Manager in your OS, e.g. Explorer on Windows, Finder on Mac)
4. Do not forget to disable extra logging once done (otherwise it will keep writing the extra info).

Comment: Thanks for that, i was able to log the activity but unfortunately it still didnt tell me what ERROR message was given by FTP server, the log simply shows time out......

https://i.imgur.com/IctIfUc.jpg 
:(

Comment: Is that a Plain FTP (not FTPS/SFTP)? Try configuring "keep alive messages", to be something like 20 secs or so -- any difference? If you have concurrent connections -- try without them. etc.

Comment: Or perhaps you have 2+ connections and switching between them during the same session?